# Express, Handlebars show flash messages

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using Node with express and handlebars. I have a login form, and should display a login error message to a user. My code is as follows:
Validation (using passport):

```
...
else if (password != user.password) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Wrong password'));
...
```

In routes I got this:

```
app.post('/sign-in', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect : '/', // redirect to the home page
        failureRedirect : '/sign-in', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

Then to render my handlebars template,

```
app.get('/sign-in', function(req, res) {
        res.render("signin.handlebars", {layout: 'users.handlebars', action: 'Sign in', message: req.flash('message'),
                    csrf: 'CSRF token goes here' });
    })
```

Problem is, the flash message ain't shown as required when a wrong password is entered.

Edit: My express setup is:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('models', __dirname + '/models');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere', resave: true, 
                        saveUninitialized: true, }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
});
```

Comment: Have you install express-flash?

Comment: I'm using connect-flash

Comment: Have you tried a simple flash message in an other route?

Comment: Yap...nothing is showing on the other page either. Is my code above correct?

Comment: What's your express setup?

Comment: I edited my question to include that...

Comment: First thing I notice is your error middleware is only setting a status and never sending a response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it btw like so:
...

```
if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'The email you entered is incorrect'
            });
```

...
That encodes the message in JSON.
Then in routes I got:

```
app.get('/sign-in', function(req, res) {
        res.render("signin.handlebars", {layout: 'users.handlebars', action: 'Sign in', ***error: req.flash('error')***,
                    csrf: 'CSRF token goes here' });
    })
```

Then in my handlebars template:

```
{{#if error}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a global variable in your index.js

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  app.locals.success = req.flash('success')
  next();
});
```

Then in your route you add the message

```
req.flash("success", "Your message");
```

Finally you .hbs

```
{{#if success}}
{{success}}
{{/if}}
```